# Create MediaWiki tag?

Tags: support, tags

Can someone with enough reputation add the "mediawiki" tag to [some of the MediaWiki questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=mediawiki+-%5Bmediawiki%5D+is%3Aquestion) please?

[Tagged questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/116580/mediawiki) are then [advertised to MediaWiki users](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Communication#Forums).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so sure it is appropriate, let alone needed. 
At a quick first glance:

- There are currently 8 questions that mention "mediawiki".
- Around half of those simply mention it in passing, and since these are not ABOUT mediawiki, they wouldn't be tagged with it;
- Most of the rest should probably be migrated to a more appropriate site (ServerFault, Webmasters.SE...) or just outright closed altogether.
- There are a couple of questions that MAY be appropriate to keep open and tag mediawiki accordingly, should be reviewed further...

I will look into this more later, unless someone else does so first...

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It's your call whether your questions belong here, but as long as they are here I think we should give them the best chances possible to be found. I make sure every MediaWiki question in SE gets answered correctly in the end, but I can't if they're not findable. :)

Comment: I'm with AviD on this - with only 2 valid questions for tagging it really isn't worth it. If we start to get more, then sure, let's add that tag, but I don't see it being useful on this site yet.